# Django views/filters

Tags: django, filtering

I have just completed the Django tutorials, and while excited about learning more, I am by no means proficient. I guess you could say that I don't know enough to be dangerous at this point.

Let's say that I have a database of music. I have an Artist model, an Album model, a Genre model, and a Song model. What I would like to be able to do is display albums (or even artists) based on given filters; so my front-end would display a list of albums and provide a means to filter the list. A "Jazz" link, for instance, would only display Jazz albums. Simple enough.

I can think of a couple ways to accomplish this, but I would like to start out on the right foot...to begin forming "best practice" Django methods. One way I can think of would be to write views...such that /albums/jazz would only display jazz. Another way would be to write model-level methods that filter the albums. Here I get a little fuzzy on how I would actually implement such a filter, however.

Will someone please give me broad overview of how this task is best accomplished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you know how to structure an app within a project (i.e. what the tutorial teaches) you can work along this example with example `models.py`, `urls.py` and `views.py` for your sample app `myapp`.

Example `models.py`:

```
class Genre(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True) # set name to be unique
    ...

class Album(models.Model):
    genre = models.ForeignKey(Genre)
    ...
```

Example `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    url(
        r'^albums/(?P<genre>[-\w]+)/$',
        ListAlbumsByGenreView.as_view(), name='list_albums_by_genre_view'
    ),
    ...
)
```

Note the `genre` parameter as the only argument in the URL pattern.

Example `views.py` using [ListView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview):

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.views.generic.list import ListView

from myapp.models import Album, Genre

class ListAlbumsByGenreView(ListView):

    model = Album

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ListAlbumsByGenreView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # fetch the genre; if genre not found, an HTTP 404 is returned
        genre = get_object_or_404(Genre, name=kwargs['genre'])
        # filter the albums by genre
        context['albums'] = Album.objects.filter(genre=genre)
        return context
```

The above ListView puts `albums` in your HTML template's context; this contains the list of albums filtered by genre.

The individually imported functions used above are all beautifully documented in the Django docs.

Comment: Thank you very much. The only line I am having trouble understanding is: 'context = super(ListAlbumsByGenreView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)'

Comment: `get_context_data` is an inherited method of `ListView` class; you have to call its `super` parent method so that you initiate the context with any context that the parent function returns. For example, if the `ListView` sets an `page_no` in the context, this call ensures this actually happens. Note that this is just an example. In this case I did it simply to follow best practices (and you should do that as well).